# Ruby on Rails 3 parent and children find only specfic children, with the parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parent-child

I have two Models, Programme and Event, a programme has many events. I need to find the programmes which have an event with a specfic date.

```
      @programmes = Programme.joins(:events).where(:events => {:date => params[:date]}).uniq
```

This works correctly. But when using

```
programme.events
```

it of course gets all events associated with a programme, how can I get just the events that match the criteria in original statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a method on programme

```
class Programme < ActiveRecord::Base
  def events_for_date(date)
    events.where(:date => date).uniq
  end
end
```

You would then call this:

```
@programme.events_for_date(params[:date])
```

You could also add a scope to the Event class, but this is likely easier to understand.

Comment: You can also implement this method as an [association extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) which relates it more closely to the `events` association.